# Is this real numbers proof formal enough?

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I want to prove that there is no real number $a$ such that $x\le a$ for all real $x$.

My attempt was: Since for all real $x$, $x\le a$, then $x+x\le a$. Substraccting both expressions, we are left that $x\le 0$. But the hypothesis was that $x$ was any real number. And since positive $x$ numbers exist, then there is no such $a$.

Even though I think my proof makes sense, I wonder whether it is formal enough for it to be valid.

I found another proof that goes like: Since $0\lt1$, then $a\lt a+1$. If we choose x to be $x=a+1$, then $x\gt a$ and no such $a$ exists.

I like the second one more, but does my attempt still count as a valid proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. For example, set $x=1$ and $a=3$. Then

$$1\leq 3$$

$$2\leq 3$$

but

$$1\geq 0$$

Your mistake is that it is not in general true for positive numbers that

$$x<y$$

$$a<b$$

implies

$$x-a<y-b$$